# Open Wounds and Skin resistance

Tags: resistance

I always read that pierced skin will dramatically affect skin resistance, but they never seem to specify where the open wounds are on the skin.

Say I have open wounds around my chest area, but I am touching something with my fingers. Does the location of these open wounds near my heart give me a greater risk, or only if the wounds are near where I am touching the electrified object?

Comment: Not "near", "on" or "in".

Comment: The difference is whether the electrode makes contact with the dead dry layers on the outside of intact skin, or the wet salty bits of the dermis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open wounds only matter if that is where the electricity is entering or exiting. For example, if you pierce your skin with two needles and connect them to a 9V battery you can potentially get a life threatening current flowing.